# HTTP ERROR 500 prbm accessing /solr/dataimport unable to configuring solr

Tags: mysql, apache, solr, lucene, jetty

Thanks, I edited my data-config.xml file

It's like this

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/lol"
user="root"
password="n"/>

<document name="content">
<entity name="id">
query="SELECT id from foo"
 </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

When I run

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

On the browser I get this

`<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst><lst name="initArgs"><lst name="defaults"><str name="config">data-config.xml</str></lst></lst><str name="status">idle</str><str name="importResponse"/><lst name="statusMessages"><str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:6.299</str><str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str><str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str><str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str><str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str><str name="Full Dump Started">2013-06-28 11:17:34</str><str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str><str name="Rolledback">2013-06-28 11:17:34</str></lst><str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str></response>`

Comment: Have you taken a look at `data-config.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 2;`?

Comment: @femtoRgon i have edited my question , plz help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that configuration should look more like (note, query should be an attribute of the `entity` element):

```
  <document name="content">
    <entity name="id" query="SELECT id from foo">
      <!--I assume you have a field in Solr and a column in MySQL, both of which are named "id"-->
    </entity>
  </document>
```